# Will HKLiveWorkoutBuilder and HKWorkoutBuilder APIs be required going forward?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, healthkit, hkhealthstore

At WWDC 2018 Apple announced HKWorkoutBuilder and HKLiveWorkoutBuilder as APIs intended to make the collection of workout statistics more straightforward.

`HKHealthStore.start` and `HKHealthStore.end` have also been deprecated in favor of `HKWorkoutSession.startActivityWithDate` and `HKWorkoutSession.end()`

However it does not appear that `HKHealthStore.execute(Query)` is deprecated.

Are developers going to be required to use the Builder APIs in upcoming OS's, or can we adopt the new start and end methods on HKWorkoutSession but still query for the data ourselves?